# how to select a radio button in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<ul>

                    <li>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input checked="checked" id="fechapublicacion" name="fechapublicacion" onclick="javascript: filtrarListado(&#39;fechapublicacion&#39;, this);" type="radio" value="0" />
                            <span>Cualquier fecha</span>
                        </label>
                        <input id="fechapublicacionhidden" name="fechapublicacionhidden" type="hidden" value="0" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input id="fechapublicacion" name="fechapublicacion" onclick="javascript: filtrarListado(&#39;fechapublicacion&#39;, this);" type="radio" value="1" />
                            <span>&#218;ltimas 24 horas</span>
                        </label>
                        <input id="fechapublicacionhidden" name="fechapublicacionhidden" type="hidden" value="0" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input id="fechapublicacion" name="fechapublicacion" onclick="javascript: filtrarListado(&#39;fechapublicacion&#39;, this);" type="radio" value="7" />
                            <span>&#218;ltimos 7 d&#237;as</span>
                        </label>
                        <input id="fechapublicacionhidden" name="fechapublicacionhidden" type="hidden" value="0" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input id="fechapublicacion" name="fechapublicacion" onclick="javascript: filtrarListado(&#39;fechapublicacion&#39;, this);" type="radio" value="15" />
                            <span>&#218;ltimos 15 d&#237;as</span>
                        </label>
                        <input id="fechapublicacionhidden" name="fechapublicacionhidden" type="hidden" value="0" />
                    </li>
            </ul>
```

I am trying to select the last radio button. Since all of them have same id, how can i select the last one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the entire html? Because the one which you have given to me works pretty well with: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/411153/47169496/

Comment: This is the link : 'http://www.infoempleo.com/ofertas-internacionales/'. There are four check boxes. I need to select the last one. All the check boxes have the same id. So i guess selecting by id will select the first check box. How can i select the last one?

Comment: `browser.find_elements_by_id("fechapublicacion")[-1].click()` ?

Comment: @NehalJWani Thanks. Got it fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `find_elements` returns list that's why you are in trouble, you should try using `find_element` instead as below :-

```
browser.find_element_by_id("fechapublicacion").click()
```

Or if you want to use `find_elements`, You should try using index in returned list as below :-

```
browser.find_elements_by_id("fechapublicacion")[0].click()
```

**Edited** :- As I'm seeing in provided HTML, I'd is not unique there and you want to select last element with the id then try using `find_elements` and select last element by passing last index as `-1` :

```
browser.find_elements_by_id("fechapublicacion")[-1].click()
```

Or you can also use `find_element` to point this element using unique `css_selector` as below :-

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input#fechapublicacion[value='15']").click()
```

Comment: Got this fixed, but still the radio button is not being selected. What can be the reason for that?

Comment: Is there any exception when you are going to click??

Comment: And make sure provided Id is unique and you are locating correct element..

Comment: Actually the id is not unique. There are four radio buttons with same id. I will edit the question

Comment: Ok then which one you want to select??

Comment: I wanted to select the last one. Got it fixed though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok then pass `-1` as index using `find_elements_by_id` see updated answer...:)

Answer (score 0):

You are using find_elements.... which returns a list. Use findelement or getelement which returns one element(i got no idea abt python functions). Or else use an index 0 to findelements. it is saying it is trying yo find a click method on a list which it aint got